# Collect the url of scraped page

Tags: import.io

Is there any way to collect the URL of the page being scraped ?
Either as a column with links or even better, the possibility to attached the url to an scraped image or text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this the same as the **Source Page URL** that you'd get when you download the crawled data?

If what you're looking for is all the links that you're visiting, you can use the **Save Log** feature from the **Advanced Crawler Settings**. This would generate a TSV file that I suggest you view in a spreadsheet. This file would let you see all converted links, failed links, blocked links, etc..